# Как сделать повторение таймера?

Tags: javascript

У нас есть таймер обратного отсчёта.

```
let timerDate = new Date("Jan 29, 2020 00:00:00").getTime();
```

И функция

```
let timerFunction = setInterval(()=>{
   let now = new Date().getTime();
   let distance = timerDate - now;

//считаем дни, часы, секунды, выводим на страницу

  if (distance < 0){
    console.log('Время закончилось');
   }


}, 1000);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы когда время заканчивалось, автоматически устанавливалась новая дата, на 1 день больше.

Например сейчас

```
let timerDate = new Date("Jan 29, 2020 00:00:00").getTime();
```

Но когда время выйдет, оно автоматически станет

```
let timerDate = new Date("Jan 30, 2020 00:00:00").getTime();
```

Я думал, что можно сделать как-то через setTime() через милисекунды, но у меня не получилось.

Заранее спасибо всем, кто поможет!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам не подошел ответ Игоря, вот работающее решение в рамках вашей функции.

Почитайте комментарии, вся логика и объяснение вынесены в код.

```js
var timerDate = new Date("Jan 22, 2020 00:00:00").getTime();
// делаем переменную глобальной, чтобы дальше её менять через цикл.

var now = new Date().getTime();
// выносим из setInterval и делаем глобальной

// пишем цикл, который проверяет чтобы timerdate был больше чем "сейчас".
// Пока этого не происходит он увеличивает таймер на сутки в миллисекундах
// (так работает UNIX timestamp - в миллисекундах).

while (timerDate < now) {
  console.log('Проверяем timerDate - сейчас это временная метка из прошлого, её нужно увеличить.');
  timerDate = timerDate + 86400000;
  console.log('Увеличиваем timerDate на сутки. Теперь значение:' + timerDate);
  // просто показываю что дата каждый раз увеличивается на сутки, 
  // пока не станет нужной. (итого 7 увеличений).
}

let timerFunction = setInterval(() => {

  let distance = timerDate - now;
  //считаем дни, часы, секунды, выводим на страницу

  if (distance < 0) {
    console.log('Время закончилось');

    // в реальных условиях никогда не закончится, 
    // т.к. цикл в начале при загрузке страницы не позволит быть timerDate < now, 
    // однако если у пользователя будет открыт сайт больше суток можно добавить сюда увеличение.

    timerDate = timerDate + 86400000;

    // На случай если браузер открыт больше суток на вашей странице. 
    //Тогда таймер дойдет до нуля, обновится и снова пойдет отсчитывать от 24 часов 59 минут и 59 секунд.

  }


}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let timerDate = new Date("Jan 29, 2020 00:00:00");
...
let distance = timerDate.getTime() - now;
...
timerDate.setDate(timerDate.getDate() + 1);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate

Comment: так не работает, получается. Время идёт в -, т.е. -... часов почему-то. И отсчет идёт не как таймер, а на сложение